# How to put Electron GUI application into Docker container?

Tags: docker, electron

I'm trying to put an Electron application into a Docker container. I have tried following this guide but no application GUI is showing:
https://medium.com/@SaravSun/running-gui-applications-inside-docker-containers-83d65c0db110

Anyone have any up to date guides for putting Electron applications into a Docker container?